# Дана действительная матрица размера 6×9 . Найти среднее арифметическое наибольшего и наименьшего значений ее элементов

Tags: python

У меня вопрос следующий: Как мне перестроить этот код так, чтобы в нем использовались `map`, `filter` и пр. функции

```
import random
m=int(input())
n=int(input())
matrix=[[random.randint(1,101) for j in range(n)] for i in range(m)]
print('Matrytsa')
 
amin = amax = matrix[0][0]
 
for i in range(m):
    amin = min(map (matrix[i], amin))
    amax = max(map (matrix[i], amax))
    
    print(matrix[i])
 
print((amax+amin)/2)
```

Comment: По-моему, вы просто в шоке - вам надо открыть документацию почитать, успокоиться и применить изученное. Нет смысла считать среднее арифметическое как наибольшего, так и наименьшего значения.:)